# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Load balancer issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image]For single Spring boot App, Successfully setup CICD using AWS CodePipeline and Elastic Beanstalk.

But now want to Deploy multiple Spring boot Services on same Elastic Beanstalk to minimize EC2 instance following below link:

[Deploying multiple services on a single instance of AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://medium.com/finnovate-io/deployment-multiple-services-on-a-single-instance-of-aws-elastic-beanstalk-f9bc00908c64)

But getting `Bad Gateway (502)` if we hit generated url given by Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: Double check all your ports and protocols (e.g., for trafic from ELB->instances, it should be HTTP, not HTTPS).

Comment: yes I have checked it, it is http, added image for reference